# Accessing current user location and showing all the users near it

Tags: python, django, postgresql, geolocation

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to `access user's current location` and showing all the user that are `nearby of the User`.

**The Problem :-**

I don't know how to access the `current location of user` and show `all the users` **near it**.

**What i am using to access location :-**

I am using `GeoDjango` , `GeoLocation` , `PostGis` , `gis` to access location of user.
All the requirements are successfully installed.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.db.models import Manager as GeoManager

class Location(models.Model):
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80,default='')
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    location  = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.place_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.latitude and self.longitude:
            self.location = Point(self.longitude, self.latitude)

        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance  

lat = 52.5
lng = 1.0
radius = 10
point = Point(lng, lat)   

def location(request):
    near_users = Location.objects.filter(location__distance_lt=(point, Distance(km=radius)))

    context = {'near_users':near_users}
    return render(request, 'mains/near_users.html', context)
```

When i run the code in browser then it shows nothing.

**What have i tried**

- I tried `places = Loc.objects.distance(user_location).first()` method but it didn't worked for me.

**Brief explanation**

First , I am trying to access the location of `request.user` then get all the users near it.

Suppose, There's a user at Las Vegas then `django access the location` as Las Vegas and finds all the users that were in LasVegas.

I don't know what to do. I didn't find anything from Internet in clean way. I think this is everybody's concern to access location.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.